# design a layout like book open and animation same as book reviewing time

Tags: android

I want to display my pages as a book, and when we move from one page to another it should look like book reviewing. For an example see the below screenshot

[image]

Can you give me some suggestions on this design and animation functionality?

Comment: What are you referring to when saying "book reviewing", are you looking to have the pages look like they're actually flipping when changing pages?

Comment: @hooked82 :sorry for that saying ,u have any idea on that

Comment: You still haven't clarified what you're looking for.  Explain your question a little further if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this ?

[image]

Code for this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical" >
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnNext" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnBack" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnNext" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBack"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layRight"
                android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="250dp"></RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layLeft"
                android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="250dp"></RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```